# HTML how to get it to display čšž on your site

Tags: html, utf-8, character

Trying to learn to make a site. And right from the start:

How do I get HTML to display ščž and other various special characters like ł,ß,ö..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a character set so the browser knows what's being used in the page.  For example, in your `head` section, try putting:-

`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

You can also try specifying symbols using their entity name/code, using the character reference table here - https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: Thanks. Also thakns for the link!

Comment: If they second way helps then the first way wasn't done correctly and should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an HTML5 example.  `meta` declares the encoding of the HTML file.  Make sure to save the file in that encoding!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>How do I get HTML to display ščž and other various special characters like ł,ß,ö,&#x9A6C..?</body>
</html>
```

You can enter any character you know the Unicode codepoint using `&#xnnnn` syntax.  In the example above, U+9A6C is the Chinese character for horse(马).

Comment: Thanks, in the end that tutorial page seems to override utf-8 and just ignore anything that is not ascii for some reason.